# Sending Red Hat audit logs to Windows Share

Tags: linux, windows, redhat, logging, audit

I am trying to figure out the best way to offload audit logs from a single Red Hat server to a windows share.  What is the best way to do this without installing any additional software on the Windows Side? I am using Audisp as my logging software.

Is my Red Hat box going to have to be on my Windows domain in order to make this happen?

OS: Red Hat 7 and Windows Server 2012R2.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use smbclient with credentials to copy the files, redirecting commands into it.  It has a lot of similar syntax to ftp.  man smbclient to get a manpage (or search on your favorite search engine).

Something like, maybe:

```
echo 'cp /var/log/audit/audit* \some\windows\dir'|smbclient //host/share -A mycredentials.txt
```

The documentation also mentions a `-c` option to pass a command string, like:

```
smbclient //host/share -A mycredentials.txt -c 'cp /var/log/audit/audit* \some\windows\dir'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to mount the drive using cifs
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/448263

You can test it using this:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=<share user>,password=<share password>,domain=example.com //WIN_PC_IP/<share name> /mnt
```

You can add this to the /etc/fstab to make it mount on boot:

```
//WIN_PC_IP/<share name>    /<mntpoint>   cifs  _netdev,username=<share user>,password=<share password>,domain=<domain name>,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755,uid=500,gid=500 0 0
```

I have noticed wonky behavior if the share goes offline, so if you know you're planning a reboot (or one happens on its own), you should unmount and remount it on the Redhat host.

Comment: Or use automount.